# How to make Flask communicate with Flask across two different machines?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app on one machine, and a second machine where some queries are required to be run from.  The second machine doesn't render any pages, it will just be doing things behind the scenes for the first app.  If I create a Flask app on the second machine to control those queries, how do I communicate with it from the first app?  Is making a second Flask app with an API correct, or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You communicate with it like you would any other HTTP server: by making HTTP requests.  Python has the built-in [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request), or you could consider the easy to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library.

If all the second machine is doing is running background tasks, there's no reason to set up another Flask app.  You can use a task queue such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) instead, or an RPC library such as [Pyro](https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).